# Can not read image with opencv2.3 imread

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

Hello I am trying to read an image by using imread function of opencv as in the link  (http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html#display-image). I have VS2010 with 64 bit windows 7. Each time I try I get error message "no image data", however the image I want to read is in the same folder with codes. Can someone please help me how to read an image with imread function? My code is as below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
using namespace cv;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Mat image;  
    image = imread("al.jpg");
    if(argc != 2 || !image.data )
    {
        printf("no image data \n");
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Display Image", image);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you find an answer helpful, be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 5):

It you can load image using

```
IplImage *img=cvLoadImage("Image_Name);
```

Then you can convert this into cv::Mat using,

```
Mat mat(img);
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem on WinXP with VS2005 and **OpenCV 2.3**. It seems that the C++ interface of OpenCV is not working well for Windows. I also had problems with `imread()`, which returned `NULL` data.

I solved the problem using the **C interface** of OpenCV instead. For more info, check [Reading and Writing Images and Video](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html).

Comment: I am having the same problem with C++ OpenCV 2.4 interface and Visual Studio 2010. I am porting code from my MAC (where I had no issues with the interface) to Windows. Is there any work around apart from converting all my code to using the C interface?

Comment: I came across this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901905/installing-opencv-2-4-in-visual-c-2010-express?lq=1 that mentions to use the updated libraries *d.lib when adding dependencies for the linker. I tried that it seems to work. Not sure if that is the case in general or not.

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same problems as yours. The **C++ interface for OpenCV2.3** didn't work and some functions have to convert to C version.
But at last, I found what the ** problem is.
That is because the project properties when you **compiled your OpenCV source code with CMake**, is not the same as your current project properties.(May be your OpenCV's dll and libs are download from the internet, and these may be compiled with other wierd properties.)
So I check my CMake generated OpenCV source code project, I found the **project property** , **C/C++-->Code Generation**, the **Runtime Library** is **Multi-threaded Debug DLL(/MDd)**.
Then, I change the corresponding property in my current project, and my project work well. At the same time, the other C++ interface for OpenCV bugs is solved well.

Comment: Thank you! you save my life.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the `argc != 2` test. You aren't using the arguments passed to your program so it's superfluous. And if `argc` is, in fact, not eaual to 2, your program is terminating before even getting to the `!image.data` test.

*Edit:* I just looked at the code sample you linked to. It loads an image whose name is passed to the program on the command line. That's why the `argc != 2` test is there. You definitely want to take that out because you are most likely not passing a file name on the command line so your `argc` is 1, thus the test will always fail.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV offers support for the image formats Windows bitmap (bmp), portable image formats (pbm, pgm, ppm) and Sun raster (sr, ras).

Answer (score 0):

I experience that same problem, This may come from VS project compilation in VS 10.

In visual studio 2010: 
Go to project --> properties --> Character set --> Use multi byte instead of unicode.

Answer (score -1):

Set the Common Language Runtime Support (/clr) in Visual C++.
It works.

Comment: How would CLR help with native libraries?