# OpenCV and VS2010: Fatal error LNK1104: atal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'tbb_debug.lib

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I tried following this guide to install OpenCV with Visual Studio C++ 2010 (using Windows 7 64-bit): [Installing OpenCV 2.4.3 in Visual C++ 2010 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901905/installing-opencv-2-4-in-visual-c-2010-express)

I am using OpenCV-2.4.2 and have therefore changed all the Additional Dependencies, e.g. from `"opencv_calib3d240d.lib"` to `"opencv_calib3d242d.lib"`.

However, I get the following error when I try to run the example code for displaying an image:

```
<quote>1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'tbb_debug.lib'</quote>
```

I have tried switching the folders from "ia32" to "intel64". I have also tried to add "tbb_debug.lib" to "Additional Dependencies" in Linker->Input.

Another thing: the location of OpenCV is on another harddrive (D:) than my OS and VS (C:), but I assume this shouldn't make a difference [edit: I have moved to C:, but still get the same problem.]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post how you specified your library directories.

Comment: Here they are:

VC++ Directories - Include Directories:
C:\opencv\build\include;$(IncludePath)

VC++ Directories - Library Directories:
C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib;$(LibraryPath)

C/C++ General - Additional Include Directories:
C:\opencv\build\common\tbb\ia32\vc10

Linker General - Additional Library Directories:
C:\opencv\build\common\tbb\ia32\vc10

Comment: Linker Input:
opencv_calib3d242d.lib
opencv_contrib242d.lib
opencv_core242d.lib
opencv_features2d242d.lib
opencv_flann242d.lib
opencv_gpu242d.lib
opencv_haartraining_engined.lib
opencv_highgui242d.lib
opencv_imgproc242d.lib
opencv_legacy242d.lib
opencv_ml242d.lib
opencv_nonfree242d.lib
opencv_objdetect242d.lib
opencv_photo242d.lib
opencv_stitching242d.lib
opencv_ts242d.lib
opencv_video242d.lib
opencv_videostab242d.lib
tbb_debug.lib

Comment: Linker - Command Line:
/OUT:"C:\Users\Wikzo\Desktop\Procedural Programming\OpenCVtest\2nd try\OpenCV_test2\Debug\OpenCV_test2.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\opencv\build\common\tbb\ia32\vc10" "opencv_calib3d242d.lib" "opencv_contrib242d.lib" "opencv_core242d.lib" "opencv_features2d242d.lib" "opencv_flann242d.lib" "opencv_gpu242d.lib"

Comment: Linker - Command Line (cont.):
"opencv_haartraining_engined.lib" "opencv_highgui242d.lib" "opencv_imgproc242d.lib" "opencv_legacy242d.lib" "opencv_ml242d.lib" "opencv_nonfree242d.lib" "opencv_objdetect242d.lib" "opencv_photo242d.lib" "opencv_stitching242d.lib"

Comment: Linker - Command Line (cont.):
"opencv_ts242d.lib" "opencv_video242d.lib" "opencv_videostab242d.lib" "tbb_debug.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"Debug\OpenCV_test2.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'"

Comment: Linker - COmmand Line (cont.):
/DEBUG /PDB:"C:\Users\Wikzo\Desktop\Procedural Programming\OpenCVtest\2nd try\OpenCV_test2\Debug\OpenCV_test2.pdb" /ASSEMBLYDEBUG /PGD:"C:\Users\Wikzo\Desktop\Procedural Programming\OpenCVtest\2nd try\OpenCV_test2\Debug\OpenCV_test2.pgd" /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /FIXED:NO /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE

Comment: This is the LAST COMMENT: First, I am sorry for posting so many comments, but there is a character limit. Second, I don't know how to properly format my text, sorry.

Comment: You could've added these comments on your answer. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem and 
Change `Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)` to  `No Common Language Runtime Support` in Configuration properties-> General->Common Language Runtime.
its works successfully.

Comment: Actually, not for me. Can you help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184641/opencv-2-4-fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-tbb-debug-lib ?