# how to install opencv 2.3 in Visual Studio 2010 c++ express?

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, image-processing

I am doing my project on offline video detection using video.Actually firstly I used opencv2.3 with Microsoft visual studio 2008 express. All algorithms were working fine but there was memory or stack problem for video so I was not able to load and play any video.
SO I switch to opencv2.4.2 with Microsoft 2010 express.and I was able to run any length of video but but many algorithms are different in opencv2.4.2. SO can anybody please tell me how to install opencv 2.3 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 express? also is it compatible?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901905/installing-opencv-2-4-3-in-visual-c-2010-express

Comment: hey thanx but its is for opencv 2.4.3. I want to insatll 2.3. so pls cn you guide for that?

Comment: I think is the same...

Comment: Still, It is much better if you go to later versions, as later means better.

Comment: but latest version has more implementation problem. opencv 2.3 has more easy function to implement.so Is that possible?

Comment: What you need to do is: Add to the system path the folder with the .dll. Usually: c:\opencv\...\bin. Then do the same that is said in the other question. It may happen that the directory paths are different, e.g instead of C:\opencv\build\include you may have C:\opencv\include or something different, but find the one with the includes inside.