# unable to run OpenCV in Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 on Windows 7 machine

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv, visual-c++-2010

I have followed the intrunctions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901905/installing-opencv-2-4-3-in-visual-c-2010-express)  to the core.

And they run perfect on Windows 7 32 bit machine. But I use the same instructions with Windows 7 64 bit machine. I get the following error.

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvDestroyAllWindows referenced in function "void * __cdecl trial1(void *)" (?trial1@@YAPAXPAX@Z)

and similarly for other openCV methods.

I have made changes in my Configuration Manager and added x64 to the Solutions Platform but still getting the errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to link the `*.lib` files in the project properties. They is a lib file for every header file included in the code. i.e. `opencv2/core` has lib `opencv_core.lib`

Comment: Jason I have added them in Liker->Input->Additional Dependencies as mentioned in the link I referred. My exact files are
--------------------------------------------------------------------
opencv_calib3d243d.lib
opencv_contrib243d.lib
opencv_core243d.lib
opencv_features2d243d.lib
opencv_flann243d.lib
opencv_gpu243d.lib
opencv_haartraining_engined.lib
opencv_highgui243d.lib
opencv_imgproc243d.lib
opencv_legacy243d.lib
opencv_ml243d.lib
opencv_nonfree243d.lib
opencv_objdetect243d.lib
opencv_photo243d.lib

but I have changed the 3 at the end to 4 since I am using OpenCV 2.4.4

Comment: Are the lib and your code both x64 or both x32? If you compile for x64, you must include x64 compiled library files and vice versa.

Comment: The libs I have included are all x64 as I am using a 64bit machine. I was able to run this code in Windows 7 64 bit using Visual Studio 2010. But I don't know why it just doesn't work in Visual C++ when used in 64 bit machine.