# opencv running tutorial test undeclared indentifier

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I have been trying to install opencv from source for a while now on i have been using the tutorials from

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html

I got as far a attempting to build the opencv test project in visual studio (i have built it in x86 but i have windows 7 (x64) dont really think it is related to the problem but just in case someone asks).

Now i build the project and I get the following errors:

```
1>l:\documents\researchproject\opencv_workspace\projects\example1\example1\test.cpp(64): error C2065: 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH' : undeclared identifier
1>l:\documents\researchproject\opencv_workspace\projects\example1\example1\test.cpp(65): error C2065: 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT' : undeclared identifier
1>l:\documents\researchproject\opencv_workspace\projects\example1\example1\test.cpp(66): error C2065: 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH' : undeclared identifier
1>l:\documents\researchproject\opencv_workspace\projects\example1\example1\test.cpp(67): error C2065: 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT' : undeclared identifier
1>l:\documents\researchproject\opencv_workspace\projects\example1\example1\test.cpp(79): error C2065: 'CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE' : undeclared identifier
1>l:\documents\researchproject\opencv_workspace\projects\example1\example1\test.cpp(80): error C2065: 'CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE' : undeclared identifier
1>l:\documents\researchproject\opencv_workspace\projects\example1\example1\test.cpp(81): error C3861: 'cvMoveWindow': identifier not found
1>l:\documents\researchproject\opencv_workspace\projects\example1\example1\test.cpp(82): error C3861: 'cvMoveWindow': identifier not found
1>l:\documents\researchproject\opencv_workspace\projects\example1\example1\test.cpp(85): error C2065: 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT' : undeclared identifier
1>l:\documents\researchproject\opencv_workspace\projects\example1\example1\test.cpp(129): error C3861: 'cvWaitKey': identifier not found
```

However when i can follow the declaration of highgui.hpp in visual to the file that contains CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH (which for some reason is opencv2/highgui.hpp not opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp but the latter references the first).
Can anyone explain to why visual studio is not finding the these identifiers?

I have read the link several times and i think i have done everything in there, i would appreciate any help as this is cracking me up.

EDIT AND SOLVED:

Right feel a bit dumb right now, but i will leave this here to others that might find this issue when compiling from github opencv and following the tutorials, the previous issue occurs because changes have occurred in from the version in the website and the one in github, please use the source code version in github (at the time of writing 2.4.9)

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/Test.cpp

In this version the CV and cv prefix from enums and methods has disappeared.

I hope this helps and sorry for putting the question and replying to it after, but i did spent a while looking at it.

Comment: This **[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901905/installing-opencv-2-4-3-in-visual-c-2010-express)** is my first tutorial and it is more straightforward.

Comment: Thanks wang ur tutorial is quite good.