# OpenCV-Cant extract the main file

Tags: opencv, extract, 7zip

I downloaded openCV2.4.0 on windows prof 64bit and each time i run .exe file it opens 7zip extractor and then an error message that cannot open OpenCV-2.4.6.0.exe as archive.
Any ideas?

Comment: It seems like the archive was not loaded correctly. Try to download it again.

Answer (score 0):

take a look here :

[Installing OpenCV 2.4.3 in Visual C++ 2010 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901905/installing-opencv-2-4-3-in-visual-c-2010-express/10901906#10901906)

or

http://4someonehelp.blogspot.in/2013/06/solved-install-opencv-245-using-visual.html

or 
[Setup OpenCV-2.3 for Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010/7014918#7014918)