# Installing OpenCV on windows and building programs with Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, opencv

I have followed many tutorials on installing OpenCV on windows including:

[Installing OpenCV 2.4.3 in Visual C++ 2010 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901905/installing-opencv-2-4-3-in-visual-c-2010-express)

[How to build applications with OpenCV inside the Microsoft Visual Studio](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html)

But the applications are not building. It says the library cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

When adding a new property sheet you have to give a list of the libs you want to link to the project when compiling the application.

It important to note that the lib names CHANGE for each version of OpenCV. i.e. the debug additional dependencies are (this is not obvious in the instructions):

Version **2.4.6** Additional Dependencies (**debug**):

opencv_calib3d246d.lib
opencv_contrib246d.lib
opencv_core246d.lib
opencv_features2d246d.lib
opencv_flann246d.lib
opencv_gpu246d.lib
opencv_haartraining_engined.lib
opencv_highgui246d.lib
opencv_imgproc246d.lib
opencv_legacy246d.lib
opencv_ml246d.lib
opencv_nonfree246d.lib
opencv_objdetect246d.lib
opencv_ocl246d.lib
opencv_photo246d.lib
opencv_stitching246d.lib
opencv_superres246d.lib
opencv_ts246d.lib
opencv_video246d.lib
opencv_videostab246d.lib

**2.4.3** Additional Dependencies (**debug**):

opencv_core243d.lib
opencv_imgproc243d.lib
opencv_highgui243d.lib
opencv_ml243d.lib
opencv_video243d.lib
opencv_features2d243d.lib
opencv_calib3d243d.lib

**2.4.6** Additional Dependencies (**release**):

opencv_calib3d246.lib
opencv_contrib246.lib
opencv_core246.lib
opencv_features2d246.lib
opencv_flann246.lib
opencv_gpu246.lib
opencv_haartraining_engine.lib
opencv_highgui246.lib
opencv_imgproc246.lib
opencv_legacy246.lib
opencv_ml246.lib
opencv_nonfree246.lib
opencv_objdetect246.lib
opencv_ocl246.lib
opencv_photo246d.lib
opencv_stitching246.lib
opencv_superres246.lib
opencv_ts246.lib
opencv_video246.lib
opencv_videostab246.lib

**2.4.3** Additional Dependencies (**release**):

opencv_core243.lib
opencv_imgproc243.lib
opencv_highgui243.lib
opencv_ml243.lib
opencv_video243.lib
opencv_features2d243.lib
opencv_calib3d243.lib