# opencv 2.4 7 installation into visual studio 2008

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2008

I have some trouble with installation opencv 2.4.7 into visual studio 2008

Can it be the problem the mismatch between opencv 2.4.7 and visual stdio 2008

visual stdio has vc10 and vc11 library do ı need the vc9 or something?

here is my error : Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.

Comment: You need to make sure you have the built openCV libraries that were built using VS2008 & VC9. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901905/installing-opencv-2-4-3-in-visual-c-2010-express) but just follow it with 2008

Comment: Can ı build the program using VS2008 & VC10 (or VC11) ? I already follow the instructions but it s not still work .

Comment: I don't know. Probably not. Someone may correct me.

Comment: I think the problem was the mismatching VS2008 & opencv 2.4.7 maybe not. But I removed the VS2008 and load the VS2012 with opencv 2.4.7 and it works now .