# Installing OpenCV 2.4.9 in Visual C++ 2010 Giving me Errors

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I have tried to install openCV to my computer. I have followed [Installing OpenCV 2.4.3 in Visual C++ 2010 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901905/installing-opencv-2-4-3-in-visual-c-2010-express) tutorial , http://www.worldofmcu.com/2013/06/installing-opencv-in-windows-7-visual.html tutorial and even a couple of youtube videos. However, I cant seem to work it. From the first, I got an error fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_haartraining_engined.lib' I have removed that error by removing it from Additional Dependencies.

Now, I got an error called The program '[6104] cvtest.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b). I have tried many of the methods suggested here step by step but I simply couldn't solve the problem. I have also tried it with different programs and the both errors are the same. This is the program that I use [Installing OpenCV 2.4.3 in Visual C++ 2010 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901905/installing-opencv-2-4-3-in-visual-c-2010-)

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat im = imread("C:\Users\İhsan\Downloads\lena.jpg");
    if (im.empty()) 
    {
        cout << "Cannot load image!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    imshow("Image", im);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

it gives me a (0xc000007b) error that I have mentioned.(After I fixed the library error) It also gives me exactly the same problems when I try this code http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgo0UitHfp8&list=LLD0fqFAKW_kKwEEdQY5IVQg&index=1 In addition, for some reason Visual does not understand Users in my code and says incorrectly formed universal character name even though that is the correct path.

My openCV is at D folder and from the system properties, I made a variable value of D:\opencv\build and system variable path of %OPENCV_BUILD%\x64\vc10\bin; I don't think thats the issue but is there a problem with openCV that I have to copy files to C not D?

I am really really disappointed and tired with these problems and I hope that you guys can help me fix them.

Comment: How is this a Java question?

Comment: btw, please use forward slashes in filenames. also, the weird İ in İhsan. i'm afraid to say, that it won't understand unicode, only ascii.

Comment: Please remove the YouTube link, and stick to 'your' question.

Comment: It understands the İ in java and android programs but still I sent the picture to D and tried that. Still has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem by installing the Visual Studio 2013 with openCV 2.4.10. I believe that the problem was the conflict between 64 bit and 32 bit paths.

I have an another question though and I have to ask here because of the limit. After I added openCV libraries, paths, etc to my solution and completed my code, I want to create a new project to that solution so that I can use my preferences or a new solution to my visual studio. However, openCV libraries are not getting added when I have done so. They don't even get added when I create a new project to the same solution. How can I fix that?