# Can't open document opencv2\opencv.hpp on visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I got an error like this when I open the document of opencv2\opencv.hpp on the visual studio 2012. 
[image]
The error is underlined below code but I still run the program
[image]

I want to open the document of library and no error code.
Can you help me! Thank you!

Comment: have you added include paths?

Comment: What is the path to your OpenCV directory?

Comment: Can you show me how to install the correct path?

Comment: just follow this guide. THere is nothing better on the net http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901905/installing-opencv-2-4-3-in-visual-c-2010-express

Comment: Thank you very much! It's correct ^^