# The program can't start because opencv_core2410d.dll is missing

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I installed **visual studio 2012**.i have windows 8.1.then i extract **opencv 2.4.10** in c partition.

Created the visual C++ project->win32 Console application.

As I have x64 machine

```
 build menu->Configuration manager->platform->x64
```

then i set below configuration in my vs project.

```
project->properties->configuration->all configuration

VC++Directories->Library Directories->
  C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin,C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\lib

C/C++->Genaral->Additional Include Derectories->
    C:\opencv\build\include,C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2,C:\opencv\build\include\opencv
```

change the

```
          Configuration->Debug
          Select Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies

    opencv_core2410d.lib
    opencv_highgui2410d.lib
    opencv_imgproc2410d.lib
    opencv_calib3d2410d.lib
    opencv_contrib2410d.lib
    opencv_features2d2410d.lib
    opencv_flann2410d.lib
    opencv_gpu2410d.lib
    opencv_legacy2410d.lib
    opencv_ml2410d.lib
    opencv_nonfree2410d.lib
    opencv_objdetect2410d.lib
    opencv_photo2410d.lib
    opencv_stitching2410d.lib
    opencv_superres2410d.lib
    opencv_ts2410d.lib
    opencv_video2410d.lib
```

then

```
   change Configuration->Release
   select Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies

    opencv_core2410.lib
    opencv_highgui2410.lib
    opencv_imgproc2410.lib
    opencv_calib3d2410.lib
    opencv_contrib2410.lib
    opencv_features2d2410.lib
    opencv_flann2410.lib
    opencv_gpu2410.lib
    opencv_legacy2410.lib
    opencv_ml2410.lib
    opencv_nonfree2410.lib
    opencv_objdetect2410.lib
    opencv_photo2410.lib
    opencv_stitching2410.lib
    opencv_superres2410.lib
    opencv_ts2410.lib
    opencv_video2410.lib
    opencv_videostab2410.lib
```

then i created a class and wrote the code

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

    int main(){
       //declare a new iplimage pointer
       IplImage*myimage;

       //load image
       myimage = cvLoadImage("D:\\visual studio 2012\\katussa.jpg",1);
       cvNamedWindow("Smile",1);
       cvShowImage("Smile",myimage);

       //wait for the key to close the window
       cvWaitKey(0);
       cvDestroyWindow("Smile");
       cvReleaseImage(&myimage);
       return 0;
    }
```

when i run i got the error message
**The program can't start because opencv_core2410d.dll is missing**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add OpenCV to your system path:

You need to add the directory C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin to your system PATH. This directory contains OpenCV DLLs required for running your code.

Open Control Panel → System → Advanced system settings → Advanced Tab → Environment variables...

On the System Variables section, select Path (1), Edit (2), and type C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin; (3), then click Ok.

ninja edit:

make sure you have follow *all* the steps on [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901905/installing-opencv-2-4-3-in-visual-c-2010-express)

Comment: In my case i had to add "C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin" to system path and it worked.thanx @GPPK

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you may get this error even when you have added the relevent bin file, for example `\opencv-x.x.x\build\install\x64\vc15\bin`, to the System Path Environment Variable.

In my case, it worked once I rebooted my PC. Or maybe just restart visual studio and see if it's working, before you reboot the system.