# c++ vs2010 access denied on debug F5

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm using visual studio 2010.
And followed a simple opencv tutorial :
[Installing OpenCV 2.4.3 in Visual C++ 2010 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901905/installing-opencv-2-4-3-in-visual-c-2010-express)

However when i hit F5 compile visual studio gives me an access denied message. LNK1104

- Restarting visual studio has no effect.
- Running as Admin has no effect.
- Completely restarted in a new project, same error.
- Non of my folders use spaces, so errors cant be related to that.
- I am below the max unc path length (old DOS bug)
- Windows security essentials (my antivirus), has this folder excluded.
- Strangly code syntax following openCV namespace etc is understood
- A compilation seams to be made, but cannt run
- Also run from a dos prompt in debug folder, same error access denied
- using taskmanager i see my exe loaded in memory, looking with sysinternals proces explorer; i see they are loaded by Devenv.exe (part of visual studio (same icon as vs2010). but well loaded but not working.
- When closing vs2010, and using procmon.exe (sysinternals), going to debug folder executing the little app i made. then cmdagent process gives one "create file" exception on the Q drive (a left over from office online). However my app isnt related to office at all, its just a small image shower, nothing reffers to that bogus Q drive ???

I somehow think the problems are related to VS2010 itself, but I have no clues of what is happening here, its one of my first c++ projects so i'm not sure where to look of what goes wrong, any help would be great.

*** update 20-3-2015
Problem whatever it is, is not related to openCV
Even the most simple C++ code like below isnt working now, what can this be ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout << "it never executes" << endl;
}
```

Whats wrong with my visual studio suddenly ???

Comment: What is the exact message? Could you kindly provide us a full stack or the screenshot? I had problems installing OpenCV on windows - and it's a buggy software in the first place. You might have to re-install visual studio 2010 express.

Comment: Try using SysInternals Process Monitor instead. Filter on Operation is CreateFile and see what file gives access denied.

Comment: I suppose you read MSDN's explanation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts7eyw4s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)... have you checked everything (disc space, environment variables, etc.)?

Comment: checked disk space folder names, environment vars etc nothing strange there. i dont use vis stud express i use the full version, reinstalling vis studio for one prj that doesnt work is no option for me. Proces monitor well nothing conclusivly from that one

Answer (score 0):

I used the installation CDrom of visual studio to repair it.
C++ works again now..

Only left in doubts if i will use openCV again or switch to Halcon.