# Create image from 2D point array

Tags: c++, image, opencv, visual-c++, image-processing

I have a 2D array of the form (x,y) coordinates. My goal is to create an image of those 2D points.

How could I achieve that?

Thank you, Alex.

Comment: Can you explain more about your problem , Image is itself is 2D array of Points.  DO you want to display or something else.

Comment: I want to generate it so later on I could apply pixel dilate.

Comment: I want to achieve an image that contains if in pixel(i,j) there's a point or not

Comment: Are you familiar with OpenCV ?

Comment: Not much but if it is the only way to achieve that I could make an effort. :)

Comment: If you are comfortable in C++ , then OpenCV is best solution here , As there is a one time minimal effort in setup and after that you can do a lot in Image Processing . and Its supports forums for OpenCV are also very helpful and active.

Comment: Then OpenCV is great. How would you solve my problem using OpenCV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Installing OpenCV 2.4.3 in Visual C++ 2010 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901905/installing-opencv-2-4-3-in-visual-c-2010-express)

This is setting up on Windows Visual Studio 2010 and OpenCV 2.4.3. you can figure out the steps if you want to upgrade on newer version of OpenCV or Visual Studio. Steps will be similar.

Above links provides a good starting point.

After that you need a basic understanding of Mat 
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html

You can start with Core Module : The Core Functionality 
this explains Mat and other related operations in detail.

You can find Erode and Dilate tutorial 
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html#morphology-1

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you,

Comment: Installing OpenCV 3.1 would be much better. Version 2.4.3 is quite old

Comment: Isn't this http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html#morphology-1 just completely the opposite? I mean, they say dilation makes the character thinner. Isn't it supposed to act the other way?

Answer (score 1):

Using OpenCV, this is roughly how I'd do it (fill in your own variables):

```
vector<Point> points {Point(x1,y1), Point(x2,y2) ... };
Mat plot(height, width, CV_8U, 255);
for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
    plot.at<int>(points[i]) = 0;
}
```

Draws black pixels at specified points on white background on a canvas that's width x height large. Your 2D points are stored as Point variables, which is a handy OpenCV way of storing, well, 2D points. (Can access individual x/y coords via point.x/point.y as needed). If you want to be fancier you could add set-up validation where the height & width of your canvas is guaranteed larger than your most far-out point - I won't write that out, though.

Comment: I have this code as my points go from 0 to 1 in x/y coordinates.

http://pastebin.com/6LgJ4p15

I'm multiplying by 400 as it is my height and width. But the overcome does not match the supposed result.

This shows: http://imgur.com/5Rr7bMI

And the supposed result is: http://imgur.com/8IncmXy

Any guess on what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using OpenCV, then,

```
int arr_TU_DI[size_rows][size_cols] = bla bla values; // pseudocode

Mat imag = Mat(size_rows,size_cols,&arr_TU_DI);
```