# OpenCV 2.4.2 imread function causing runtime error

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm a starter in OpenCV. My programming environment is VC++ Express 2010 + OpenCV 2.4.2 + Win 7 64 bit.

I use purely 32bit configuration in my VC++ and Path.

I type in the following code:

```
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char* imgPath = "logo.png";
    Mat img = imread(imgPath);
    namedWindow( "Example1", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Example1", img);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I compile and run. It does come up with a window (but without picture) but then gave me this (a runtime error?)

```
Unhandled exception at 0x770515de in Helloworld2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x001ef038..
```

Then I change the imread into cvLoadImage and it works without any errors.

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the code you have given. It works perfectly fine with my installation of OpenCV.

However I am getting a warning at the line:

```
char* imgPath = "logo.png";

main.cpp:6:21: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-
```

Wwrite-strings]

Which i think is nothing serious to make the code crash, however it might be the problem in your case, as I am not using VC++ to compile.

What you can try to check if this is the issue is to replace `imgPath` with directly the string, so the code will now be like

```
Mat img = imread("logo.png");
```

Answer (score 1):

I also got this issue, but I fixed it with the following. The point is using absolute path other than relative path, and change "\" with "/" in the file path.

```
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

int main() {
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("D:/projects/test/Debug/1.jpg");
    if (image.empty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    cv::namedWindow("my image");
    cv::imshow("my image", image);
    cv::waitKey(5000);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `cvLoadImage` and `imread` can be seen on opencv documentation:

> C++: Mat imread(**const string& filename**, int flags=1 )

and

> C: CvMat* cvLoadImageM(**const char* filename**, int
>   iscolor=CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR )

But there is an implicit conversion from `const char *` to `string`. As masad noted, this conversion is deprecated, so it is very compiler dependent.

As `cvLoadImage` works for you, it seems that you should change your code to something like this:

```
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include <string>
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::string imgPath("logo.png");
    Mat img = imread(imgPath);
    namedWindow( "Example1", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Example1", img);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

There has been some [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7015015/634150) with C++ interface in Visual Studio, but you may try to see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I came across [Installing OpenCV 2.4.3 in Visual C++ 2010 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901905/installing-opencv-2-4-in-visual-c-2010-express?lq=1) and it mentions to use the updated set of libraries *d.lib when adding dependencies for the Linker. I tried it and the C++ interface worked. Not sure if this is the case in general. I am using OpenCV 2.4 and Visual Studio 2010 on a 64 bit Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar problem with you. When I use the imread function, the program crash with system error message:
*opencv_debug.exe 中的 0x0036299f 处未处理的异常: 0xC0000005: 读取位置 0xcccccccc 时发生访问冲突*

Then I change the imread into cvLoadImage and it works without any errors.

**Finally, I fix the problem, it comes because I used VS2008 project with VS2010 compiled dll**.

Here is my story.

Environment: **VS2008 + opencv2.4.7**

First, I just follow the link http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html, and compile the my test project.

But, When I run my test project, the system error dialog tells me that I lost *MSVCP100D.dll MSVCR100D.dll*. So I download the two dll, the dll lost problem is solved, but the problem is crash on run time.

Notice that ahead link, it says:
[image: setx command]

it means that, in opencv2.4.7, they only provide dlls which compiled in vs2010 or vs2012, not vs2008.

When I compiling vs2008 project with dlls which compiled by vs2010, I get the wired problem.

How can I fix this problem?

1. use the older opencv version such as opencv2.3, this version contains the vs2008 compiled dll.
   [image: vc9]
2. compile the opencv by yourself.

I have noticed that your environment is: VC++ Express 2010 + OpenCV 2.4.2 + Win 7 64 bit. 
Be sure OPENCV_DIR is set right.

setx -m OPENCV_DIR D:\OpenCV\Build\x64\vc10